# Adding Android source (AOSP) to version control

Tags: git, version-control, android-source

I am looking to create a local copy of the Android source (AOSP) on my local system.
So I want to add version control (git) on the local SDK.

I am able to clone the AOSP from the vendor, but now I want to manage the SDK on my local system.

after clone AOSP, removed all .git and .repo files from the source, and able to create empty git with "git init --bare".

But when I am trying to add the file using "git add -Rf ." some files missing and not able to add to version control

Is there any way we can add all required files to local version control?

Comment: You keep mentioning the SDK and AOSP. What do you want to have in git? The SDK or the full source code of Android? IMO both are probably better *not* stored in a single git repository, but putting all of AOSP in a single repo is *bound* to cause issues. It's quite immense.

Comment: It's immense but git is quite good. I've done this before, and talking from experience, it's not thaat bad, but yeah in some cases some operation might cause you to wait 10-20 seconds to finish.

Repo tool and Gerrit are the prefered way to go for AOSP

As for some files that you say are missing, likely they are ignored by some .gitignore. Use git check-ignore

Comment: @RickSanchez Can you provide me the steps to follow as you did in past?

Comment: Same as you.  Removed all .git folders and .repo, the "git init" ( without bare), and add/commit.

Comment: A tip: some repos have some files tracked and later added in .gitignore ( meaning they are still in git as .gitignore doesnt ignore tracked files ). When you init git first time .gitignore will ignore those files and cause you issues.   A workaround I do for this is to rename all .gitignore in .gitignore_bak, add/commit everything, and rename them back to .gitignore and commit.     This migh not be needed in all distros, but was needed on RK/QCOM BSP